# GCP VM Instance: Server Timed Out Error - Intermittently

Tags: wordpress, apache2, google-compute-engine

[cloud web security scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDVRV.jpg)1. Setup a WordPress site on localhost
2. Setup GCP Fresh Account for it
3. Created a New WordPress CE Instance [Login details, etc]
4. Migrated local site to GCP successfully [config cloud dns and update remote dns registrar]
5. SSL installed through Lets Encrypt
6. Updated urls with wp commands
7. Direct ssh access through the VM Instance Dashboard works
8. SFTP works
9. Started experiencing intermittent Server Timed Out Error [On and Off] for 24hrs!
10.Decided to migrate the instance to another region/zone [from asia-east-1a to us-west-2a]
11.Seems to works better in the new region/zone
12. Server timed out Error continues.

checked for site health
dnslookup resolve to correct domain and ip
dig +trace matches correct name server
pings replied icmp echo

I ruled out load balancing as the site is small and no traffic yet....
Is this GCP zone issue or Compute Engine issue? I have no idea.
[browser snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyhH1.jpg)
Even SSH from the dashboard takes forever to login or timed out also
[SSH snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrpYO.jpg)
All help, pointers and support are greatly appreciated!

site: https://geexse.com
[different browser snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOlll.jpg)

Comment: The WP is directly exposed to internet? Or there is a LB in the middle? Could you describe your data/request flow?

Comment: Thanks @ArdenSmith. No LB in the middle, directly connected. I wouldn't know maybe there's misconfig error in the WordPress setup script in GCP. 
I later migrate my data and create a fresh compute engine VM instance, provision the server and everything seems is all fine now.

Comment: Cool! Share your workaround